# Spark SQL FIRST() function equivalence in Presto

Tags: apache-spark-sql, presto

What is the equivalence of the [FIRST](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/index.html#first) Spark SQL function in Presto?

```
WITH test (
  select 2 as id,
  'something 2' as name
  union
  select
  3 as id,
  'something 3' as name
  union
    select 1 as id,
  'something q1' as name
)

SELECT  FIRST(name) FROM test
```

Returns: "something 2" in Spark. I've been looking for an example in Presto. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you used first_value() function, that will be able to give you the data you are looking for.